MongoDB unable to store token in session
I am working on a project that can fetch posts from Facebook using meta API. The facebook callback function returns the token, however I am having trouble to save it in the session. The session seems to be created, but it does not add the access token.
export const facebookCallback = async (req, res) => {
    const { code } = req.query;

    if (!code) {
        console.error("Authorization code missing in callback");
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Authorization code not provided" });
    }

    try {
        // Step 1: Get short-lived token
        const tokenResponse = await axios.get(
            `https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/oauth/access_token`,
            {
                params: {
                    client_id: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                    redirect_uri: process.env.FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL,
                    client_secret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                    code,
                },
            }
        );

        const shortLivedToken = tokenResponse.data.access_token;

        if (!shortLivedToken) {
            console.error("Failed to retrieve short-lived access token");
            return res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to retrieve short-lived access token" });
        }

        // Step 2: Exchange for long-lived token
        const longLivedToken = await exchangeForLongLivedToken(shortLivedToken);
        console.log('Long lived token:', longLivedToken);

        // Step 3: Save token in session and set the cookie explicitly
        req.session.accessToken = longLivedToken;
        console.log('Session accessToken set:', req.session.accessToken); // Explicitly log session token

        // Ensure the cookie is set properly
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 3600000; // Optional: ensure session is valid for 1 hour
        req.session.cookie.httpOnly = true; // To prevent client-side access
        req.session.cookie.secure = process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "production"; // Set secure flag for production

        // Save session
        req.session.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error saving session:', err);
                return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to save session' });
            }

            console.log('Session saved successfully:', req.session);

            // Send the cookie with the response
            res.cookie('connect.sid', req.sessionID, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "production", // Use secure cookies in production
                sameSite: 'lax',
                maxAge: 3600000, // 1 hour cookie
            });

            // Redirect to client-side
            const clientUrl =
                process.env.ENVIRONMENT === 'production'
                    ? process.env.PRODUCTION_CLIENT_URL
                    : process.env.LOCAL_CLIENT_URL;

            return res.redirect(`${clientUrl}/admin/projects/new/facebook`);
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during Facebook callback:', error.response?.data || error.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to complete Facebook login' });
    }
};

Here is how the session is set up:
app.use(
    session({
        name: "connect.sid", // Default session cookie name
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        resave: true, // Allow the session to be re-saved even if it was not modified
        saveUninitialized: false, // Do not save empty sessions
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.ENVIRONMENT === "production", // Set secure cookies in production
            sameSite: "lax", // Helps prevent CSRF
            maxAge: 3600000, // 1 hour
        },
        store: MongoStore.create({
            mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI, // MongoDB URI for storing sessions
            ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 14 days TTL for session
            autoRemove: "native", // Automatically clean up expired sessions
        }),
    })
);

So when I make request from the front-end to fetch facebook pages it cannot extract the token from the session.
    fetchFacebookPages: async () => {
        try {
            console.log("Fetching Facebook pages...");
            const response = await http.get("/admin/facebook/pages");
            console.log("Pages fetched:", response.data.pages);
            return response.data.pages;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching pages:", error.response?.data || error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    },

here are my logs:
Session saved successfully: Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2024-12-06T13:12:33.062Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: 'lax'
  },
  accessToken: '********'

Validating token: 
Session in Middleware: Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2024-12-06T13:12:34.096Z,
    originalMaxAge: 3600000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false,
    sameSite: 'lax'
  }
}

}

Access token missing from session



My http interceptor:

import axios from "axios";

// Function to fetch the client's public IP address
async function fetchIPAddress() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');
        return response.data.ip;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch IP address:', error);
        return null;
    }
}

// Create an Axios instance
const http = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
        ? `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api`
        : "http://localhost:3001/api", // Default to localhost if environment variable is not set
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    withCredentials: true, // Send cookies with requests
});

// Request interceptor to add additional headers
http.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        const ipAddress = await fetchIPAddress(); // Fetch public IP
        if (ipAddress) {
            config.headers['X-Client-IP'] = ipAddress; // Add IP to request headers
        }
        console.log("Request Headers:", config.headers); // Log headers for debugging
        return config;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error("Request Error:", error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

// Response interceptor to handle success and error responses
http.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        console.log("Response Data:", response.data); // Log response data
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error("Response Error:", error.response?.data || error.message);
        return Promise.reject(error); // Pass error to the calling function
    }
);

export default http;


And this is the component that is supposed to fetch pages:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import adminServices from "../../../API/adminServices";
import styles from "./FacebookFetch.module.css";
import arrow from "../../../Assets/arrow.svg";
import AdminLoader from "../../../Shared/AdminLoader/AdminLoader";

const FacebookFetch = ({ setDescription, setLinks }) => {
    const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});
    const [activePageId, setActivePageId] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (window.location.hash === "#_=_") {
            window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.pathname);
        }

        const autoLoginAndFetchPages = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            setError(null);
            try {
                const fetchedPages = await adminServices.fetchFacebookPages();
                setPages(fetchedPages);
            } catch (err) {
                if (err.response?.status === 401 && !localStorage.getItem("facebookRetry")) {
                    console.log("No valid token found, redirecting to Facebook login...");
                    localStorage.setItem("facebookRetry", "true");
                    handleFacebookLogin();
                } else {
                    console.error("Error fetching pages:", err.message);
                    setError(err);
                }
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        autoLoginAndFetchPages();
    }, []);

    const fetchPages = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setError(null);
        try {
            const fetchedPages = await adminServices.fetchFacebookPages();
            setPages(fetchedPages);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error fetching Facebook pages:", err.message);
            setError(err);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const fetchPosts = async (pageId) => {
        setLoading(true);
        setError(null);

        try {
            setPosts({});
            setActivePageId(null);

            const selectedPage = pages.find((page) => page.id === pageId);
            const fetchedPosts = await adminServices.fetchFacebookPagePosts(
                pageId,
                selectedPage.access_token
            );

            setPosts({
                [pageId]: fetchedPosts,
            });
            setActivePageId(pageId);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error fetching posts:", err.message);
            setError(err);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const handleFacebookLogin = () => {
        adminServices.redirectToFacebookLogin();
    };

    const selectPost = async (post) => {
        setLoading(true);
        setError(null);

        try {
            const selectedPage = pages.find((page) => page.id === activePageId);
            if (!selectedPage?.access_token) {
                throw new Error("Page access token is missing.");
            }

            if (!post.message && !post.attachments) {
                setError("This post has no content to fetch.");
                return;
            }

            const postData = await adminServices.downloadPostMedia(post.id, selectedPage.access_token);

            const description = postData.description || "";

            // Extract only non-media links from the description
            const linkRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
            const extractedLinks = description.match(linkRegex) || [];
            const cleanedDescription = description.replace(linkRegex, "").trim();

            // Combine API links and extracted non-media links
            const combinedLinks = [...(postData.links || []), ...extractedLinks].filter(
                (link) => !postData.media.includes(link) // Exclude media URLs
            );

            // Set description and cleaned links
            setDescription(cleanedDescription);
            setLinks(combinedLinks);

            // Navigate and pass the appropriate data
            navigate("/admin/projects/new", {
                state: {
                    description: cleanedDescription,
                    links: combinedLinks,
                    media: postData.media, // Separate field for media
                },
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error("Error selecting post:", err.message);
            setError(err.message);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            {loading && <AdminLoader />} {/* Show loader during loading */}
            <h1 className={styles.title}>
                Fetch From <span className={styles.facebook}>Facebook</span>
            </h1>
            <div className={styles.actions}>
                <button className={`primary__btn`} onClick={handleFacebookLogin}>
                    Configure
                </button>
                <button className="primary__btn" onClick={fetchPages}>
                    Refresh Pages
                </button>
            </div>
            {error && <p className={styles.error}>Error: {error.message || "Unknown error"}</p>}
            <div className={styles.content}>
                <div className={styles.pages}>
                    <h2>Pages</h2>
                    {pages.length > 0 ? (
                        <ul className={styles.pageList}>
                            {pages.map((page) => (
                                <li key={page.id} className={styles.pageItem}>
                                    <button className={styles.pageButton} onClick={() => fetchPosts(page.id)}>
                                        {page.name}
                                        <img className={styles.arrow} src={arrow} alt="arrow" />
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    ) : (
                        <p>No pages found or not logged in.</p>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className={styles.posts}>
                    <h2>Posts</h2>
                    {Object.keys(posts).length > 0 ? (
                        Object.entries(posts).map(([pageId, pagePosts]) => (
                            <div className={styles.posts__list} key={pageId}>
                                {pagePosts.map((post, index) => (
                                    <div key={index} className={styles.post}>
                                        <div className={styles.wrapper}>
                                            <p className={styles.postMessage}>
                                                {post.message || "No message or content provided."}
                                            </p>
                                            {post.message && post.message.match(/https?:\/\/[^\s]+/g) && (
                                                <div className={styles.postLinks}>
                                                    <strong>Links:</strong>
                                                    {post.message
                                                        .match(/https?:\/\/[^\s]+/g)
                                                        .map((link, i) => (
                                                            <a
                                                                href={link}
                                                                key={i}
                                                                target="_blank"
                                                                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                                                                className={styles.link}
                                                            >
                                                                {link}
                                                            </a>
                                                        ))}
                                                </div>
                                            )}
                                            <button
                                                className={`${styles.selectPostButton}`}
                                                onClick={() => selectPost(post)}
                                            >
                                                Select Post
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        {post.full_picture && (
                                            <img
                                                src={post.full_picture}
                                                alt="Post content"
                                                className={styles.postImage}
                                            />
                                        )}
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <p>Select a page to view posts.</p>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default FacebookFetch;


Here are the back-end routes:
// Facebook routes
router.get("/facebook/login", facebookLogin);
router.get("/facebook/login/callback", facebookCallback);
router.get("/facebook/pages", ensureValidAccessToken, getUserPages);
router.get("/facebook/posts/:pageId", ensureValidAccessToken, getPagePosts);
router.post('/facebook/post/download', ensureValidAccessToken, downloadPostMedia);

This is the validation function that throws the error
export const ensureValidAccessToken = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Session in Middleware:", req.session);
    if (!req.session.accessToken) {
        console.error("Access token missing from session");
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "No token provided!" });
    }
    next();
};

I tried debugging a lot, but I cannot find out why it is not saving the token.

Could you provide a complete example? There are missing parts on the code provided

Sorry for that, I added more code

Access Token does not get saved in the mongoDb session at all, however a session is being created
